# function.name in JS for WASM module

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I am [playing around with WASM in nodejs](https://github.com/dotnetCarpenter/node-wasm) and noticed that [`function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) for a WASM module is `0`, even though my WAT file export a function name.

**Why does a WASM module not set the export name? Is there any performance issues with WASM setting the export name in `function.name` in JS? Is this nodejs specific or missing in WebAssembly spec?**

I hope my question is clear. I want to know why `function.name` is `0` for a WASM module.

I am using `wabt`@1.0.13 to compile a simple WAT file.

```
(module
  (func $add (param i32 i32) (result i32)
    (i32.add
      (local.get 0)
      (local.get 1))
  )
  (export "add" (func $add)))
```

And the same code with `wasm2wat` from the compiled WASM file:

```
(module
  (type $t0 (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (func $add (type $t0) (param $p0 i32) (param $p1 i32) (result i32)
    local.get $p0
    local.get $p1
    i32.add)
  (export "add" (func $add)))
```

*add.wasm*

```
asm`add
         j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the exported Wasm function is [defined to be the index.](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/js-api/index.html#name-of-the-webassembly-function)

You already have the actual exported name since you have to import `add` by its name.

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Exported_functions where they call `testFunc.toString()` and the resulting function has name `0`.